# Run jenkins with service account on windows

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way i can change the user the jenkins run without losing existing jenkins data/cofig.  I tried changing the user in services.msc, however it crashed jenkins and was not able to load jenkins after changing user.

ps. Actually there are couple of jobs in which clone(git, tfs) happening with some user, however when it comes to running scripts/commands i get permission and attribute(readonly) issues as Jenkins is not running with same account that was used to clone repositories

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your new user has not privileges on Jenkins home folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins in my case). Just check rights on this folder.